# Cannot read property 'installCoreFunctions' of undefined

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am trying to integrate Reanimated 2.0 in iOS React Native swift project and getting the below error. Android App is working fine but not get the solve for iOS.

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/

`Error: Requiring module "node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/Animated.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'installCoreFunctions' of undefined, js engine: hermes`

**Package Info :**

> "react": "17.0.2",
>
> "react-native": "0.67.0",
>
> "react-native-reanimated": "2.3.1"

Hermes is Enabled.

Babel plugin is set for reanimate

Done multiple time node_module clear and cache reset.

Answer (score 2):

you have not done plugin config, in this case it looks like BABEL problem

please read => https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation

make sure you done all there, if u done all from this and still not working then try

npm:

```sh
npm start --reset-cache
```

yarn:

```sh
yarn start --reset-cache
```

if still ... then remove "node_modules" and redownload them by "yarn" or "npm" ( if u r on mac and doing ios development u have to "cd ios && pod install" )

```sh
rm -rf node_modules
```

Comment: Done all of this. But still not luck.

Comment: then there is 1 more hthing remove again node modules package and do all as admin, if node doesnt have rights then scripts inside node_modules cant execute correct

Comment: Tried, but still its the same error.

Comment: Didnt work for me.
Also - error Im getting when building in Android Studio is "Task 'assembleDebug' not found in project ':react-native-reanimated"

Comment: Also - error doesnt occur with RN 0.66.0

Answer (score 1):

Did you add Reanimated's babel plugin to your babel.config.js? Like so:

```
  module.exports = {
      ...
      plugins: [
          ...
          'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      ],
  };
```

There can also be a permission error, try running `chmod +rwx ./node_modules`

Comment: Plugin was already added.. Tried with permission but still the same error.

Comment: Same for me...plugin added and no luck

Answer (score 0):

I was using `initWithBundleURL` to initialise the the rootView I changed it to `initWithBridge` which helped me resolve the issue.

```
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                            launchOptions:launchOptions];
  
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"appname"
                                            initialProperties:initialProps ];
```

You might have to implement `sourceURLForBridge` something like this

```
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
    return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
}
```