# React-Native navigation drawer application, TypeError: Cannot read property 'installCoreFunctions' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation-drawer

Long story short I'm trying to make an react-native App that uses Drawer Navigator, but I get this error in metro and I don't know how to fix this error.

```
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'installCoreFunctions' of undefined, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

My dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.12.0"
  }
```

I also set the `enableHermes` property in \app\build.gradle to true as some of the solutions said but I didn't solve the error

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

If there is any other files I should paste in here

Comment: reply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70813232/cannot-read-property-installcorefunctions-of-undefined

Comment: @hongdeveloper the later answear answear worked, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'installCoreFunctions' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70813232/cannot-read-property-installcorefunctions-of-undefined)